# Enable Zsh prompt username

Tags: zsh

So I just installed Zsh, and it shows for each command arrow and then ~. How do I enable my username@computername or something similar? I am reading https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh but cannot figure this out.

That's how it looks now: [image]

Comment: Just a comment: You can install Oh-my-zsh and that includes LOTS of zsh "themes" that have different prompt styles, looks, and colors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The prompt is configured in your `~/.zshrc` file setting the variable `PROMPT`. For example, to have your username and host followed by a "dynamic" `%`:

```
~ PROMPT="%n@%m%# "
romano@samsung-romano%
```

The whole set of customization is available in the, as ever, [wonderful Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Customizing_the_prompt).

Anyway, I warmly advise the usage of [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt) --- notice that once installed it will install a mechanism to control the prompt so that changing the `PROMPT` variable will not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks Rmano, for some reason my zsh is messed up. I cannot change as you said (even thought I know it's supposed to work), mane commands do not work either in the shell for some reason.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, it solution works for me :P . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I may help you understand what had happened here.

By the picture you attached, it looks like you had installed [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh) on your machine.

You could have:

1. customized the prompt by choosing one of the [integrated themes](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes)
2. created a [custom theme](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Customization#overriding-and-adding-themes)
3. [uninstalled Oh My Zsh](https://askubuntu.com/a/963877/1180307) altogether and set the PROMPT variable like @Rmano described in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483861/1180307)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes

In order to enable a theme, set ZSH_THEME to the name of the theme in your ~/.zshrc, before sourcing Oh My Zsh; for example: ZSH_THEME=robbyrussell If you do not want any theme enabled, just set ZSH_THEME to blank: ZSH_THEME=""

ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

Answer (score -1):

- Open up a terminal and type:

  ```
  nano ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Then copy the code and paste at the end of the file.

  ```
  export PS1="\u@\h \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
  ```
- Save and exit by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Finally, type `source ~/.bashrc` and you will be able to see the changes.