# Uninstall Oh My Zsh

Tags: command-line

I installed `Oh My Zsh` by using the following command so how do I uninstall it?

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 41):

From [the `oh-my-zsh` README](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#uninstalling-oh-my-zsh):

> #### Uninstalling Oh My Zsh
>
> Oh My Zsh isn't for everyone. We'll miss you, but we want to make this
>   an easy breakup.
>
> If you want to uninstall `oh-my-zsh`, just run `uninstall_oh_my_zsh`
>   from the command-line. It will remove itself and revert your previous
>   bash or zsh configuration.

Answer (score 14):

I had to change the permissions of my `uninstall.sh` file for this to work. My `uninstall.sh` was read-only. Changing it to `777` did the trick!

```
$ sudo chmod 777 ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh
$ ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

If `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` doesn't works, you can run the `.sh` file directly:

```
source ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run the following command:

```
sh ~/.oh-my-zsh/tools/uninstall.sh
```

You will be asked the following:

```
Are you sure you want to remove Oh My Zsh? [y/N]
```

Then enter `y` for "yes" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will restore `.zshrc` and remove the `~/.oh-my-zsh/` folder.